# Issues with MySQL code?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, create-table

I"m getting an error somewhere around PRIMARY KEY but can't figure out what exactly it is, can someone take a look?

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (

    `key`                   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
    `region`                VARCHAR(70),
    `inspection_type`       VARCHAR(70),
    `inspection_number`     VARCHAR(70),
    `customer_number`       VARCHAR(70),

    `report_date`           DATE DEFAULT NULL,  



    `order_date`            DATE DEFAULT NULL,  


    `customer`              VARCHAR(70),
    `customer_division`     VARCHAR(70),
    `location`              VARCHAR(70),
    `memo`                  VARCHAR(255),       
    `billingkey`            VARCHAR(70),

    PRIMARY KEY(key)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Comment: And that error would be...? Why do people do this?

Comment: If it isn't to late to rethink your column name, you ought to pick something other than `key` to save yourself more trouble later on.

Comment: @micharl It can't be helped, it's a client requirement, not something I can negotiate with... =(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose `key` in backquotes. It is a [MySQL reserved keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

```
PRIMARY KEY(`key`)
```

Comment: +1 Better yet, don't name your column key if possible. Too much potential for future errors here IMO.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is a reserved word.  Technically, you'd have to do:

```
PRIMARY KEY(`key`)
```

to use it, but don't call your primary key `key`.

Comment: +1 Because you were typing it as a comment at the same time I was putting an answer...

Comment: I lookup the list so often for SO answers that when I start typing `my` in Chrome, the MySQL reserved keywords list pops up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the word key, it's a reserved keyword:

```
.
.
.     
PRIMARY KEY(`key`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```